# How to do versioning for a static library using vc++

Tags: visual-c++

I want the version details to be set for static dll or library using vc++. 
If i see the properties dialog box there is no version tab for this static dll's. 
I want to create this version tab and include the version info for the static dll's. 
Pl help me

Comment: There is no such thing like "static dll", as "dll" is shortcut for "dynamically linked library"; did you just mean "static library"?

Comment: Ya what i meant is static library

Answer (score 1):

The [version information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058%28VS.85%29.aspx) on resource file work with [Version Information functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). These functions are based on LoadLibrary.

You can not use it for static libraries, only for dll and exe files

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you mean with a static dll but in general what you need to do is to add a .rc file to your project containing the versioning information. If you have already a .rc file then just add a version record in it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: This .rc file can be included ly for the dll. I am unable to add this for the static library

Comment: the versioninfo gets included in the static lib as well, but you need to read it from your program, the OS doesn't seem to give the same support. You can see it by just looking at the produced .lib using some text viewer, you will then see the version info.

Comment: but that .lib file when opened in text viewer its not as the one in the program. Unable to read that file. Is there any better way to do this